# How to hide and show array elements without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, show-hide

So I have an Array and I would like to be able to hide and show each element of the array just by clicking it using vanilla JavaScript. Although I am a little confused on how to use the `getElementById` in this instance because it's an array...

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="js/sender.js"></script>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="style" media="screen">
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sub" id="main">
  </div>
  <ol id="list"></ol>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var sender:[bob, sally, syke, lucy, larry,];
for(var i =0; i<sender.length; i++){
var liBody = document.createElement("li");
liBody.IdName = "main";
liBody.innerHTML = sender[i]; 
document.body.appendChild(liBody);
```

}

Comment: what's the `var sender:[bob, sally, syke, lucy, larry,];` supposed to be?

Comment: Oh sorry! Its the array of information that I am trying to work with.

Comment: What will you be clicking to show each array item?

Comment: this is not a complete code. What are trying to click? You should be able to print all of array items using for loop. I can help but you need to post complete code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Krishna, you can't show/hide elements of an array. DOM doesn't work with arrays, it works with DOM elements. You need to create a JavaScript function that takes your array and for each element in the array does something (i.e. adds an DOM element inside a parent you specify). Than you can define listeners for interacting with the DOM elements. Like, for example hide/show them when a particular event is ran on a particular list of DOM elements that act as controls for your elements. In its current form, your question is quite unclear and lacks any kind of research. Therefore, is offtopic.

Comment: you may not be able to show/hide directly but you could add/remove a class that changes the display (which is how jQuery works) Or you could remove the item from the DOM and re-add it (side effect being bad for SEO)

Comment: This is the complete for loop, im sorry im just learning DOM and really still learning javascript, but im trying!

 for(var i =0; i<info.length; i++){
var liBody = document.createElement("li");
liBody.IdName = "main";
liBody.innerHTML = info[i].body; //retrieving info from another 
file 
document.body.appendChild(liBody);}

Comment: I gave you a simple example. However, keep in mind [SO] is a place where you're supposed to ask after you (re)searched and tried everything you could think of and it didn't work. Nobody here will code for you for free and this is also not a place where you can learn to code. You're supposed to know programming when you ask here. And the only way to learn to code is to code, IMHO. Take it slow, go through tutorials, change and break things. You can't skip steps. I mean, you can, but you'll need to learn them later on and it will probably seem harder overall.

Comment: Im not asking for someone to write my code for me. Ive spent days researching Toggle, Onclick, addEventListener() and everything. I dont have any of my code on here for those because they havent worked and they were very wrong. I am not one of those who want someone to do it for me, I wanted to learn thats why I asked here.

Comment: If you don't post your tries, we're going to assume you haven't tried anything. Posting faulty code is the best way to learn. People will tell you what's not ok with it and teach you better ways.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to display each of the array items in a list, and toggle the array items' visibility on click. If I'm understanding your question correctly, here's one way to do that:

```js
var sender = ["bob", "sally", "syke", "lucy", "larry"];
var myList = document.getElementById('list');

for (var i = 0; i < sender.length; i++) {
  var liBody = document.createElement("li");
  var spanWrapper = document.createElement("span");  //wrapper to handle the clicks
  spanWrapper.style.display = "block";
  liBody.IdName = "main";
  liBody.innerText = sender[i]; //pulling value from sender array
  liBody.style.visibility = "visible";
  spanWrapper.addEventListener('click', function() { //add click handler
    if (this.childNodes[0].style.visibility == "visible") {
      this.childNodes[0].style.visibility = "hidden";  //hide item
    } else {
      this.childNodes[0].style.visibility = "visible";  //show item
    }
  });
  spanWrapper.appendChild(liBody);  //add list item to its span wrapper
  myList.appendChild(spanWrapper); //add span wrapper to the list
}
```

```html
<div class="sub" id="main">
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

This code loops through your `sender` array and assigns each array element to a `<li>`. Each `<li>` is placed inside a `<span>` for the purpose of handling any clicks and toggling the item to be visible or hidden.

Clicking on each list item (which is populated from your `sender` array) will hide that item if it's currently visible, or show it if it's currently hidden.

Unless the `<li>`'s `IdName` property serves another purpose not seen here, you can remove this line from your code:

```
liBody.IdName = "main";
```

You also had an extra `</div>` tag that shouldn't be there, and unless the names in your array are actually variables, your array declaration should like this:

```
var sender = ["bob", "sally", "syke", "lucy", "larry"];
```

rather than this:

```
var sender:[bob, sally, syke, lucy, larry,];
```

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense. So each li is set into a different span?

Comment: @KrishnaPatel You got it. Each `span` is just a wrapper for the `li`, so that when you click the `li` and make it disappear, there's still something there to register when you click again to make it reappear.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>


<ul id="list"></ul>


<script>
    list = document.getElementById('list');
    items = ['item 0', 'item 1', 'item 2'];
    for (x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
        li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(items[x]));
        list.appendChild(li);
        list.childNodes[x].setAttribute('onclick', 'hide(' + x + ')');
    }

    function hide(pos) {
        list.childNodes[pos].style.display = 'none';
    }


</script>


</body>
</html>
```